# Error : Cannort create a connection to Data Source 'XYZ' in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I have deployed a SSRS report for the user.But while accessing the report from the report server user is getting the below error

[image]

But I and some of the users are able to access the same report,Please suggest me.Do i  need to add him in any Security

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The user that is connecting to the report needs to have access to the database that the data source is.  You can use stored credentials if the level of database access is not as important.

You can also instead add them to a user group that has certain read access to the database instead of giving them direct access etc.

This depends mainly on the security you need in the database.

Below you can see how to setup a report server connection:

[Report Server Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159133.aspx)